# Build SymPy matrix by alternating rows of two square matrices

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I have two square NxN matrices in SymPy.  Lets say

```py
from sympy import Matrix
x = Matrix([[1,2], 
            [3,4]])
y = Matrix([[5,6], 
            [7,8]])
```

What is the best way of creating a new 2NxN matrix which alternates rows to generate the following:

```py
z = Matrix([[1,2],
            [5,6],
            [3,4],
            [7,8]])
```

I can do it with lists and loops, but I will need to do this operation with very large matrices so I am trying to find a solution that is more efficient given I know the sizes of the matrices ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack the two matrices horizontally using `Matrix.hstack` into a 2x4 matrix, and then reshape to a 4x2 matrix. Since reshaping gathers entries by scanning across the rows, this will produce the row-alternating behavior you're looking for:

```
>>> Matrix.hstack(x, y).reshape(4, 2)
Matrix([
[1, 2],
[5, 6],
[3, 4],
[7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
In [44]: from sympy import Matrix
    ...: x = Matrix([[1,2],
    ...:             [3,4]])
    ...: y = Matrix([[5,6],
    ...:             [7,8]])

In [45]: l = [None]*4

In [46]: l[::2] = x.tolist()

In [47]: l[1::2] = y.tolist()

In [48]: Matrix(l)
Out[48]: 
⎡1  2⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎢5  6⎥
⎢    ⎥
⎢3  4⎥
⎢    ⎥
⎣7  8⎦
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Matrix.vstack` and some slicing,

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import Matrix

x = Matrix([[1,2],
            [3,4]])
y = Matrix([[5,6],
            [7,8]])

stacked = Matrix.vstack(x, y)
result = Matrix.vstack(stacked[::2, :], stacked[1::2, :])

print(sym.pretty(result))
```

outputs

```
⎡1  2⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎢5  6⎥
⎢    ⎥
⎢3  4⎥
⎢    ⎥
⎣7  8⎦
```